# Cold start rpm issue

Tags: toyota, rpm, cold-start

My car Toyota Allion 2005 with 80000 Kilometres. Recently I have my mechanic cleaned the throttle body (TB) and the idle air control (IAC) bulb.

Before cleaning the TB and IAC, parking/neutral rpm used to start at 2000/2200 at cold and gradually fall down to 800 when engine got heated.

After cleaning the TB and IAC, parking/neutral rpm starts at cold from 1400 and gradually rises to 2200. After that, the rpm falls to 800 when engine get fully heated.

Please comment on this change in cold start rpm after cleaning the TB and IAC.

Comment: Do you suspect something is wrong here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did new car cold engine startup begin at 2k-2.2k rpm? If yes then did the mechanic adjust the iacv? If not then something is amiss and requires more diagnosing. Some IACVs are adjustable but electronics tends to readjust them to return it to optimal configuration. Sometimes meddling with the factory adjusted (and fixed) throttle stop screw may upset the engine computer. The iacv is computer controlled for all rpm settings; cold engine, ac loads, high electrical loads, deceleration during closed thottle mode from speed, etc.

Comment: OP is asking if the change in behavior is a fix, normal, expected behavior - or - was the old behavior correct and now something is broken. My 2008 mazda has always been the 'before' behavior. My 2022 jeep wrangler new appears to be 'after' behavior if that helps any?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I suspect that parking/neutral rpm has changed behaviour after cleaning. Assuming that the behaviour was right before cleaning, something has gone wrong after cleaning. I am asking for your suggestions what might have gone wrong.

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you think might be wrong.  Why did you have the TB and IAC cleaned in the first place?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was experiencing poor acceleration. My mechanic suggested me to change the spark plugs and clean the TB and IAC. After cleaning, the idle rpm has got an inverted U curve instead of a downward slope which I used see before cleaning. I suspect there might be a vacuum leak but my mechanic has checked it to nullify my suspicion. He has also scanned the car but found no fault code. I don't why the idle rpm has changed.